# Updating R and R packages on a centOS7 server

Tags: r, linux, centos7

I have two questions. Our centOS7 server currently has v3.4.1 of R and we'd like it updated to v3.4.2. I've tried `sudo yum update R` in the terminal but it didn't recognize that R needs any update. Is there another recommended approach?

Also, we'd like to update R packages in the server. What would be the best approach to do so? On a local computer with R Studio running, I tend to just use the "Update packages" button.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the repo you're using hasn't updated its version of R.  I'm not well versed enough with centOS but a lot of distros don't update their version of R once they release.  There typically are ways to get the newest version but just using the out of the box repos typically won't allow you to get the newest release.